# Reading from file And 2d Array With Arraybound Warning

Tags: java, arrays, file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] clothesDb = new String[10][10];
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                    "C:/Users/irapple/Desktop/Project db/clothes.txt");
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
            String str;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }

            int count = 0;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] dividedLine = str.split("\t");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    clothesDb[count][i] = dividedLine[i];
                }
                count++;
                System.out.println(clothesDb);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


>>>ID   Order       Type    Color       Price 
>>>1    M-T-Shirt   A       Red         20000$
>>>2    W-T-Shirt   B       Blue        30000$
>>>3    K-T-Shirt   C       Yellow      35000$
>>>4    M-Pans      D       Green       75000$
>>>5    W-Pans      E       Gray        80000$
>>>6    K-Pans      F       Purple      60000$
>>>7    Hat         G       White       15000$
```

This is what I want to use it as an 2d array and I don't know how I can do with split method         exactly
and What should I do if I use \t for words and \t\t for another ones.and the final question is how can Scanner Class help for my porpuse(generate this file to 2d array)?

Comment: Have you heard of array.length?

Comment: @user1071777 U know I Know But My problem is spiliting and storing in 2d array Still i don't know what u mean exactly!

Answer (score 0):

In your case it looks more like a fixed size so I suggest you use [sub string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```
yoursting.subString(startIndex,endIndex);
```

to fill your array.

Your example :
Get rid of the inner for loop with i and replace it with code like this

```
clothesDb[count][0] = str.subString(0,20).trim();
clothesDb[count][1] = str..subString(21,40).trim();
clothesDb[count][2] = str..subString(41,60).trim();
clothesDb[count][3] = str..subString(61,str.length).trim();
```

Comment: What does trim do? Sry For Asking Because I'm new in java.

Comment: And another problem is String str index?

Comment: Trim removes  spaces from the start and end of any string... You should be able to in string documentation api

Comment: I dont understand your other comment.

Comment: yet I have the first problem The StringIndexOutOfBandException for str String, You Know ?

Comment: @AmirhoseinIp i hope you are not using the code as it is and trimming it based on your indexes. you you use the code as it is then you will get a StringOutOfBoundsException.